# Read BLE Indications in in reverse order

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working with a BLE compatible health device (that can store Measurements) to read data using android app. I am able to scan services and setup indications on a particular characteristic that stores the readings. While I am able to listen for indications and obtain the values, the indications start from first reading saved on the device to the latest reading on the device, it takes a lot of time to get the latest value (especially as the device stores large number of values).

Is there a way I can get the latest reading first so I can stop reading further older values which are unnecessary for me.

Here is piece of the code relevant to enabling Indications for the desired characteristic.

```
public static final UUID CCCD = UUID.fromString("00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");

Boolean gattsetchar = gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true);
if (!gattsetchar){
    Log.e(TAG, "set characteristic=" + gattsetchar);
}

BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(CCCD);
if(descriptor != null){
    if ((characteristic.getProperties() & BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_INDICATE) != 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Enabling Indication");
            descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_INDICATION_VALUE);
    }
}
Boolean writeDes = mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
Log.d(TAG, "Write Descriptor " + writeDes + " " + descriptor.getCharacteristic().getUuid());
```

Comment: can you put some snippet how you are listening to the Characteristic?

and those methods :
[ onCharacteristicRead, onServicesDiscovered, onCharacteristicChanged, broadcastUpdate ]

Comment: @xelilof I have updated the question with code

Comment: Then you gotta listen for the broadcasts and changes just implement the functions I mentioned 
you should connect once, and keep listening for broadcasts
not each time connecting and reading everything

Comment: I am listening for broadcasts and am not connecting and reading each time. Once the broadcast starts there is one message for every reading stored on the device. So if there are 50 readings I get 50 messages. The problem is I get these messages in sequence from 1-2-3....-50. What I am looking is at a possibility where the sequence can be 50-49-48...-1.

Comment: I am not sure, if you can change the broadcasting rules from the Device within the GATT API, 
maybe you need to upgrade the Device Program to enable many broadcasting subscriptions,  for example asc, desc, skip 10 and so on..